# how to access http local woocommerce api localhost through flutter

Tags: wordpress, flutter, authentication, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to create a flutter application using woocomerce API.

for that woocommerce i have created in my localhost

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:ecommerce_store/config.dart';
import 'package:ecommerce_store/models/customer.dart';

class APIService {
  Future<bool> createCustomer(CustomerModel model) async {
    var authToken = base64.encode(
      utf8.encode(Config.key + ":" + Config.sceret),
    );
    

    bool ret = false;

    try {
      var response = await Dio().post(
        Config.url + Config.customerURL,
        data: model.toJson(),
        options: Options(headers: {
          HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Basic $authToken',
          HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json'
        }),
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 201) {
        ret = true;
      }
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      if (e.response?.statusCode == 401) {
        ret = false;
      } else {
        ret = false;
      }
      // print(e);
    }
    return ret;
  }
}
```

but when I try to do post-operation am getting

```
{
  "code": "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view",
  "message": "Sorry, you cannot list resources.",
  "data": {
    "status": 401
  }
}
```

I saw that to access localhost API we need to use oauth1 but can anyone help me how to convert basic auth to oauth1

Thank you very much in advance